# The Guard Of Fantasy

Tags: riddle, rhyme, literature

I am back with a second riddle, hope you enjoy this and I expect some to answer it correctly within a matter of time.

> Here I will live and here I will stay,
>   as I will guard this all today.
>   This is my property is what you may not believe,
>   as some would take me for a meme.
>   But alas a day came, 
>   when three came tip tapping on my lane.
>   I let two pass as they were to young,
>   but the real target was the old one.
>   I met my match as though they would say,
>   as I am 6 feet under all today.

Comment: The general rule is when you post a puzzle it contains no hints, and you add hints if no one has the answers in a few hours

Comment: Oh, shall I remove them, also thanks for catching my mistakes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are

> The troll under the bridge in the [Billy Goats Gruff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_Billy_Goats_Gruff)

Here I will live and here I will stay
as I will guard this all today.

> He guards the bridge

This is my property is what you may not believe
as some would take me for a meme

> You wouldn't expect the bridge to be guarded by a troll, and a 'troll' is a joke, like a meme

But alas a day came 
when three came tip tapping on my lane

> The goats

I let 2 pass as they were to young
but the real target was the old one

> He let two past as they promised the next would be bigger

I met my match as though they would say
as I am 6 feet under all today

> The big goat hit him really hard and he fell in the river (hopefully dead)

Comment: I knew I made it too easy, good job

Comment: @SmailBarkouch, I quite enjoyed, I think you need to make the hints a bit more cryptic though

Comment: I'll try to make it more cryptic next time as my riddle gave to much info like you said.Thanks for the advise!

Comment: @SmailBarkouch always happy to help a new user!

Comment: Isn't this trivia??

Comment: @Sid, I don't think so, probably more literature